I want to use my exisiting chrome profile and the chrome exe with webdriver, however goto Url doesnt work
i am trying to use my own chrome profile when using webdriver, so the code runs as far as opening the chrome  browser, but goto URL doesnt work
'
    Dim Options As New ChromeOptions()
    Options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2")
    wd = New ChromeDriver("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", Options)

    wd.Navigate.GoToUrl("www.yahoo.com")
    wd.SwitchTo().Frame(0)
'

